# Function with return boolean value

Tags: swift, function, return, boolean

I am having hard time understanding the purpose of returning a boolean value in function.

For example:

```
func withdraw(amount: Double) -> Bool {
    if balance > amount {
        balance -= amount
        return true
    } else {
        println("Insufficient funds")
        return false
    }
}
```

What does it mean by `return true` or `return false`? What is the difference between `return true` and `return false`?

Why do you want to return `true` or `false` instead of a function without any return?

What is the value of `true` or `false` gonna be used for after it is returned from calling the function?

Thank you.

Comment: YES / true if the text field should implement its default behavior for the return button; otherwise, NO / false. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619603-textfieldshouldreturn?language=objc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's modify your sample a little to try to let the code answer your question self-explanatory:

```
var account = Account(startAmount: 0.0)

func hasALotOfMoney(account: Account) -> Bool {
    let fuckingRich = 1000000000
    if account.balance >= fuckingRich {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

func canBuyANewHouse() -> Bool {
    // Usage of function that returns a boolean
    if hasALotOfMoney(self.account) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
if canBuyANewHouse() {
   // go and buy a house
} else {
   // go and get more money
}
```

Comment: I have edited my example so it is more general question. In the edited example, what is the purpose of you `return true` or `return false`?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: thank you very much for your patience and so sorry for my stupid question.